# Is it possible to use methods from Ruby library in my own class?

Tags: ruby, class, vector, matrix

I am trying to define Ruby classes for vectors and matrices. I intend to define two classes, `MyVector` and `MyMatrix`, with methods as hinted below. `MyVector` should represent a row vector, `MyMatrix` should represent a matrix, internally organized as an array of `MyVector` objects. Intended methods for `MyVector`:

1. `#initialize` method, that takes an array of integers as argument.
2. `#length` method, that returns the size of the vector.
3. `#*` method, taking argument `a`, that:

   - if `a` is a vector, returns the inner product, validating that the size of `a` matches the receiver.
   - if a is a matrix, then it returns the product of the receiver and the matrix, validating the size compatibility.
4. `#to_s` method, that returns a string representation of the receiver.

Methods for `MyMatrix`:

1. `#initialize` method, that takes an array of arrays as argument, converts the inner arrays into row vecotrs (`MyVector` class), and arranges them into a matrix.
2. `#transpose` method, that returns the receiver transposed.
3. `#*` method, that takes `MyMatrix` object argument and returns the matrix product, validating size compatibility of the argument.
4. `#to_s` method, that returns a string representation of the receiver.

This code I have written so far is below, but it doesn't work at all. I tried to define some method followed by the library class method (in matrix and vector class, they already define those method), but seem this way doesn't work because it always asks you to define something new. Could you please help me? Thanks!

```
class  MyVector 
  def initialize (a)
    if !(a.instance_of? Array)
      raise "must be an array"
    else
      @array = a
    end
  end

  def array
    @array
  end

  def to_s
    @array.to_s
  end

  def length
    @array.length
  end   

  def each2(a) # 
    raise Error, "Integer is not like Vector" if a.kind_of?(Integer)
    Vector.Raise Error if length != a.length
    return to_enum(:each2, a) unless block_given?
    length.times do |i|
      yield @array[i], a[i]
    end
    self
  end

  def * (a)
    Vector.Raise Error if length != a.length
    p = 0
    each2(a) {|a1, a2|p += a1 * a2}
    p
  end
end

class MyMatrix
  def initialize a
    @array=Array.new(a.length)
    i=0
    while(i<a.length)
      @array[i]=MyVector.new(a[i])
    end
  end

  def to_s
    @array.to_s
  end

  def transpose
    size=vectors[0].length
    arr= Array.new(size)
    i=0
    while i<size
      a=Array.new(vector.length)
      j=0
      while j<a.length
        a[j]=vectors[j].arr[i]
        j+=1
      end
      arr[i]=a
      i+=1
    end        
    arr[i]=a
    i+=1
  end   

  def *m
    if !(m instance_of? MyMatrix)
      raise Error
      a=Array.new(@array.length)
      i=0
      while (i<@array.length)
        a[i]=@array[i]*m  
        i=i+1      
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `Define two classes MyVector and MyMatrix [...]` No. I do not obey your orders.

Comment: @sawa: You can see that this is just a matter of the asker's English.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I suspect it is not the OP's own word and that it was originally used in a different context, which would be a reason to close vote this question.

Comment: @sawa: I also have my doubts about the firmness of dedication of the asker to the topic, but my mood today gives zer the benefit of doubt =)

Comment: So it's possible this is just an exercise, in which case my question is moot. But if you need a matrix, have you seen NMatrix and MDArray? The former works with standard Ruby and the latter with JRuby, and they're both much faster than anything you can write in pure Ruby. http://sciruby.com

Answer (score 3):

A great question, and a great exercise for a newbie. As you might already know, [Marc-André Lafortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8279) has written the [basic Matrix / Vector library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/index.html), that is a part of Ruby standard library. While after the amount of effort that a programmer and mathematician, that Marc-André is, has put in the project, it is no longer possible to say that it sucks, it is also fair to say that stdlib `matrix` nowadays does not yet conform to that heavenly, dream-like quality that we expect of Ruby libraries.

My major criticism is that, just like you, Marc-André also makes a distinction between `Vector` and `Matrix` classes. This distinction shouldn't be: Vectors are simly matrices, whose second dimension is equal to 1. Separating `Matrix` and `Vector` leaves the user at loss as to which one to use, and that led me to banning `Vector` completely in the code that I write.

Neveretheless, it will be stdlib's `matrix`, that is going to be the answer to your post. If I understood it well, the question mark statement in your post seems to be:

"I tried to define some method ... but seem this way doesn't work because it always asks you to define something new. Could you please help me?"

In order to help you, I would answer: Start by using the `matrix` standard library. Simply type

```
require 'matrix'
```

In the next step, you will make a private copy of `matrix` library, that came with your Ruby installation, you will rename it to `my_matrix`, and require it no longer by `require 'matrix'`, but by:

```
require './path/to/my/project/directory/my_matrix'
```

In the third step, you will start changing the behavior of the library that you just copied, and see when it breaks. Next, you will learn about [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing_frameworks_for_Ruby), and learn to use stdlib's `minitest`. With that, you can define the desired behavior, and change the code until it meets the requirement.

In the 4th, 5th, ... nth step, you will be making a lot of big and small mistakes. And should your dedication to matrices and vectors in Ruby survive, you will be warmly welcome as a member of [`NMatrix` team](https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix), the future grand version of representing matrices in Ruby.